# extracting subfolders with specific name from external hard drive using osx terminal.

Tags: macos, terminal, directory

I have a large data set located on an external hard drive. I need to extract only a certain set of data/subfolders. Each folder on the drive contains amongst others subfolders named X and Y. Only subfolders named X and Y are of interest to me. What I want to end up with is a hard drive (or a separate upstream folder) containing only subfolders X and Y.

So far I have used two approaches. 1) Manual relocation of all subfolders of interest to a separate folder. 2) Deleting all folders that are not of interest to me.

The problems I have ran into is that one cannot move all subfolders X and Y into one file manually, because they have the same folder name. Deleting all folder except the folders of interest using find . -name  -exec rm -rf {} \; seems quite a hazardous approach for a layman like myself.

What is the most straightforward, non hazardous way to go about this problem using **osx Terminal**?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've oversimplified your question. But if I understand it correctly, this should work for you:

```
mkdir $HOME/Desktop/interestingdata
tar cvCf /Volumes/datasetHD/datadir - */X1 */X2 | tar xCf $HOME/Desktop/interestingdata -
```

This will extract, e.g. `/Volumes/datasetHD/datadir/(anydirname)/X1` into `$HOME/Desktop/interestingdata/(samedirname)/X1` while **not** doing the same to `/Volumes/datasetHD/datadir/(anydirname)/Y1`, etc.

(It will also include `X2` and any other `Xy` you add to that command line, in the form of `*/Xy`)

Hope that helps. If not, we can probably do better with some more specific information.